# Trim data where some cells contain space, some contain formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large amount data in an Excel file. I have over 3000 rows which cross A to CZ columns.

Before I start using the data, I need to trim all of it.

When I use VBA it takes a long time and I get error "Type not match".

Some cells contain space, some contain formula, some contain formula link with another Excel file.

```
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.HasFormula = False Then
            cell.Value = Trim(cell)
        End If
    Next cell
```

It want to trim the cells which do not have a formula but it gets the error.

Comment: How can a SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) have a formula? Isn't HasFormula overkill?

Comment: kindly remind. i have Dim cell As Range

Comment: so should i remove the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)<---what is the meaning?
i am a noob. i just find the reference code and change something.

Comment: after i remove the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), it's still got "type mismatch" error

Answer (score 1):

Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Finish will quickly remove leading/trailing spaces.

```
dim i as long

with Worksheets("Sheet1")
    for i=.cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column to 1 step -1
        with .columns(i)
            .cells.TextToColumns Destination:=.cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                                 FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
        end with
    next i
end with
```

BTW, if you want to reduce multiple interim spaces (e.g. `data    data` to `data data`) to a single space, you need to use `Application.Trim(...)` not `VBA.Trim(...)`.

Comment: so the code is use to remove the space right?, would it trim the formula?
sorry i am not so understanding the code

Comment: after i test it, it's still show me the "type mismatch" error, is it the formula problem?

Comment: No, not a formula problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If Not IsError(cell) Then
cell = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
End If
Next cell
```

finally i use this code to ignore the error. i know it is not a good method.